# Redux Toolkit: Update state of localstorage after removing item from cart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit

I am making this Food delivery app, with redux-toolkit, rtk query,NextJS and TS.
So, adding the cart functionality is working fine. But the problem arises, when I remove an item from the cart.

### Problem

If I remove an item from the cart, it gets removed and the UI updates accordingly. But in the food menu page, it is not updated properly. So, If I add an item to the cart, the previously removed item also gets added. I checked the localstorage in browser application by opening two tabs. It gets updated properly.

### What I have done

So, here is my addToCart and removecart functionality:

```
addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const itemIndex = state.items.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (itemIndex >= 0) {
        if (state.items[itemIndex].quantity_available === 0) {
          return state;
        }
        state.items[itemIndex].quantity += 1;
        state.items[itemIndex].quantity_available -= 1;
        state.items[itemIndex].total_price =
          (state.items[itemIndex].price + state.items[itemIndex].vat) *
          state.items[itemIndex].quantity;
      } else {
        state.items.push({
          ...action.payload,
          quantity: 1,
          quantity_available: action.payload.quantity_available - 1,
          total_price: action.payload.price + action.payload.vat,
        });
      }
    },
 removeCart: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action);
      return {
        ...state,
        items: state.items.filter((elem) => elem.id !== action.payload),
      };
    },
```

Here is how I added the store to the localstorage(using redux persist library):

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { foodcartSlice } from "../features/slice";

import { api } from "../services/products";

//import redux persist
import {
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

import useFoodCartReducer from "../features/slice";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "cart",
  version: 1,
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, useFoodCartReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
    cart: persistedReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).concat(api.middleware),
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

### Possible solution

What I have done in the cart page is that using a window.location.reload inside useEffect, which is every time I visit another tab and then go back to the cart page, it gets reloaded. Yes, If I do the same on the food menu page, the whole thing is solved. But then, no one wants reloads on every page visit. What I have done in the cart page is below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleVisibilityChange() {
      if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener(
      "visibilitychange",
      handleVisibilityChange,
      false
    );
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange);
    };
  });
```

I was thinking, if I can do something in the reducer method, to get the items from localstorage after every removal or addition of items, it could work. So, I added the following method:

```
 reloadCart: (state, action) => {
      console.log("state", state, action);
      return {
        ...state,
        ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:cart")!), // yes I used redux persist for saving in localstorage
      };
    },
```

### Problem of the reloadCart method:

So, first of all without the null assertion, I get the error **type null is not assignable to type string**. If I add null assertion, I get loads of error in the cart and other components because my data in localstorage gets messed up big time.
So, apart from the page reloading part, anyone got any solution on how to do this in RTK and NextJS?

Comment: Your question is missing a major piece of the puzzle—how and where are you writing to localStorage?  You will need to update your localStorage value as a side effect of both the addToCart and removeCart actions.

Comment: Does this accurately describe the situation? You have two separate windows open and you want the changes in one window to impact the other.  In that case a visibility change listener might be a good solution.  However instead of reloading the whole page, your event handler can parse the localStorage and dispatch some sort of ‘resetState’ action to update the redux state to the latest localStorage value.

Comment: @LindaPaiste okay I am adding the redux persist code. And I have used visibility change in my other project using only context and useReducer hook. If you see the useEffect I have included, there are basically no difference except in the if block I used the dispatch  like you said in my previous project. But in this case, I am unable to do that, because you can't add side effects on reducer functions or slice.

Comment: If you are using redux-persist then you shouldn't have to do any direct interaction with localStorage. What I mentioned in my previous comment re "parse the localStorage and dispatch some sort of ‘resetState’ action to update the redux state to the latest localStorage value" is something that redux-persist already does.  It sounds like redux-persist is not playing nicely with Next.js and is not re-hydrating when it should.  Try these setups and see if either works https://lightrains.com/blogs/redux-persist-with-next-js/ (simpler) or https://www.robinwieruch.de/redux-persist-next-js/

Comment: It seems like you may be missing the `<PersistGate>` component and the `persistor = persistStore(store)`.  If so, that's why it's not working.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I added the persist gate in my _app.tsx file 
```
let persistor = persistStore(store);
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Also, both of your tutorials use redux rather than using redux-toolkit, which I have already seen.